# How to refresh in EF 6, including all child objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've upgraded from EF 4 to EF6
I can't find a way of Refreshing my objects like I did in EF4
EF 4 Code

```
myDb.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, TerminalSession1.TerminalTransactions);
```

In EF 6.0 I'm having to do something like

```
myDb.Entry(TerminalSession1).Reload();
```

But I don't know if this will load the child objects as well.

Is there a better way to do this refresh?

Comment: i just dispose of my context, then create a new one and requery